# jquery on live(click) submit form

Tags: jquery, html, click, submit, live

what I want to do, this I have a drop down box that lets my admin users rate pictures G rated and X rated. once they have selected this option I would like the form to be submitted.

I thought it would be as easy as sending the form ID, but seems not.

this is the only thing the user needs to do in the form.

the html form looks like this

```
<form id="photo1">
<input id="1" name="pictureid" hidden /> 
<select name="phototype">
 <option value="G">G Rated</option>
 <option value="X">X Rated</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to submit the form when the onchange event is fired, this is the code:

```
$('#photo1 select').change(function () {
        $("#photo1").submit();
    });
```

Comment: +1, I would also add that the form needs an action and a method more than an Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#photo1 select').change(function() {
    $('#photo1').submit();

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough

```
$('select[name="phototype"]').change(function(){
  this.form.submit();
});
```

It finds the relative form automatically, so it can apply to multiple forms as well.

---

Or if you want this with `.live()` due to loading forms dynamically, then use

```
$('select[name="phototype"]').live('change',function(){
  this.form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code currently is that your user can't select "G-rated", because it's selected by default.  You should add a blank option. You probably also need a value for your hidden element:

```
<form id="photo1">
    <input id="1" name="pictureid" value="1" hidden /> 
    <select name="phototype" id="phototype">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="G">G Rated</option>
        <option value="X">X Rated</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

You could then use the following jQuery:

```
$('#phototype').change(function() {
    if (this.value) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngeCt/)

Answer (score 0):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/nLSJV/)

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();   
});

$('select').live('change',function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();   
});
```